# JQ в input - submit

Tags: html, jquery, css

Нужно, чтобы кнопка submit при наведении мыши меняла свой бэк. Style внутри тега принципиален, поэтому не могу делать через hover.
 
При таком коде реакции нет никакой. Что я делаю не так?

```
<input type="submit" value=" " class="*название класса*" 
style="background:      url(*ссылка на картинку*); width: *px; height: *px;  border: none;"
onmouseover="this.src='*ссылка на картинку*'" onmouseout="this.src='*ссылка на картинку*'">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` в таком обработчике - это html-элемент, в данном случае `input` с типом `submit`. У элемента `input` **нет** свойства `src`.

Но у него есть: `style`, у которого уже есть `background`.

Таким образом код должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
onmouseover="this.style.background='url(*ссылка на картинку*)'"
```

**Важно:** если путь обрамлен кавычками, их надо экранировать с помощью обратного слэша, например: `url(\"path/to/image\")`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Получилось. Теперь буду знать.